# Get how far scrolled horizontal scroll bar is

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

How can you get how far scrolled (in pixels) a horizontal scroll bar is scrolled? I've tried looking through other answers but that only addressed vertical scroll bars and I can't figure out how to translate it to horizontal.

Comment: Scrollbar in which control? embedded or `HScrollBar` control?

Comment: It's a Scrollbar embedded in a SplitContainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `splitcontainer` is used to split an area in to two. Controls are not added to the `SplitContainer` itself. I assume you have added the controls in `SplitContainer.Panel1` and `SplitContainer.Panel2` to read those values try the follwing.

```
int p1Hscroll = splitContainer.Panel1.HorizontalScroll.Value;
int p2Hscroll = splitContainer.Panel2.HorizontalScroll.Value;
```